# Custom Drawable draw method crashes app

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

The view creates the player and his image and passes the image down

```
    private void init(){

        int h = 1920;
        int w = 1200;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Bitmap.createBitmap(h,w, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
        Bitmap playerImage =
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.player_image);
        Player hunter = new Player(1920,1200,canvas, playerImage);
        draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         super.onDraw(canvas);
         hunter.draw(canvas);
    }
```

The custom drawable draw method. Narrowed the issue down to when we call the player's draw method.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(playerImage,(float)myX,(float)myY,new Paint());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have an instance variable named `hunter` or this wouldn't compile - you're setting a method variable named `hunter` in your `init` method and this isn't used anywhere.

Change the line to this:

```
hunter = new Player(1920,1200,canvas, playerImage);
```

You probably need to do the same for `playerImage`, it's hard to tell because this isn't complete code and you haven't provided the error message.

Comment: That fixed the issue of crashing, but the program still doesn't display the image.